# How to increase the session timeout in Symfony

Tags: session, symfony, symfony1, timeout

I would like to know how to increase the session timeout in symfony. Is it enough to only adjust the symfony configuration settings or must I also configure anything in my php.ini file?

Answer (score 29):

For Symfony 2.0.x

```
framework:
    session:
        lifetime: 43200  #time in seconds
```

For Symfony >= 2.1.0

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 43200  #time in seconds
```

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, you can find this documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#lifetime).  It's also worth pointing out that one of the things this will affect is login expiry time.

Comment: However, that parameter configures de lifetime for the cookie  (not for the session indeed) resulting that sessions are closed after the specified time since creation (they are not renewed).

Comment: How to achieve this in Symfony >= 2.1.0 when user is using PDOSession ?

Comment: @Nis That looks like something to open a separate question for :-)

Answer (score 9):

**for sf1.0**:

Change the value in *apps/appname/config/settings.yml*:

```
all:
  .settings:
    timeout:    1800 #session lifetime value in seconds
```

**for sf1.1+**:

Add these lines to *apps/appname/config/factories.yml*:

```
user:
  class: myUser
  param:
    timeout:    1800 #session lifetime value in seconds
```

Comment: Hi there!

Thanks for the help! Is this configuration enough or some other change needs to be made on php.ini file?

Thanks in advance, 
Best regards!

Comment: This is all you need - symfony manages its sessions independently to the settings in php.ini.